# Sonar installation server

Tags: sonarqube

I tried installing Sonar as mentioned in the sonar installation tutorial

but am unable to do so due to server error. This is the error I am getting:

"Unable to get version of server http://localhost:9000: Query: http://localhost:9000/api/server/index"

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some posts on my blog about installing/upgrading SonarQube http://qualilogy.com/en/category/sonar/sonar-installation/

I recommend you start with a simple installation without any plugin and then add the plugin and try with Eclispe.

Don't hesitate to ask for further precision (telling where your installation is failing).